# How to professionally ask someone to give you appropriate and achievable timelines in a project

Tags: professionalism, communication, contracting, consulting

I work in company x and my role require that I have to work closely with company Y.I am a contractual worker and I am supposed to complete my project within the stipulated period.However I have not been able to hit any of the deadlines,since company Y is a blocker in a way that my job would only move on if they submit certain projects to me.I have written a lot of emails to them to let them know that we are in a time crunch.I try to give them a sand-witch feedback whenever they revert back to me.I let them I know that I understand their busy schedule,however my team awaits the result of this project.

They give me timelines which they never meet.They do not communicate the progress of the project.This has a led to a lot of distrust in  my ability to deliver.There are chances that I could get permanent employment in this company x,however,with all that has been happening.I stand a little chance to have this opportunity.

How do I get this company Y to stick by their words when they commit to deliver at a certain time?I feel that they don't respect our agreement at all.

Kindly guide me through how to also explain to my company that this project also depends on how company Y deliver to me,Without looking like am trying to blame other people.

Answer (score 6):

> Kindly guide me through how to also explain to my company that this
>   project also depends on how company Y deliver to me,Without looking
>   like am trying to blame other people.

I would suggest you build a project plan, clearly showing where you are blocked by company Y.  I believe you can to this without flat out saying "This is company Y's fault".  Continue to refer back to the plan, and when a date is missed, just point out the facts.  **Facts only**.

You should also *communicate with your superiors the moment they miss a milestone*, while expressing "Not only did they miss the date, this lapse will now impact my date".

> How do I get this company Y to stick by their words when they commit
>   to deliver at a certain time?

Ask your management if there are any fines or penalties against company Y for missing deadlines, a well structured contract will contain such an actionable clause.  My guess is that the contract signed between company Y and your organization doesn't contain such a clause.  ( Its worth a shot though )

Comment: Actually I'd say that your second part is irrelevant.  The OP can't control company Y, and after escalating the problem to his boss it is no longer the OP's problem.