# How do I deal with the co-worker who is over promising

Tags: colleagues, teamwork

Let me give you a brief idea of the situation I am in.

I work in a Media Industry as a Software Developer. Our team has 3-4 people and one of the co-workers is very Noisy. He starts boasting everything, over promising delivery which is certainly not possible. Sometimes he makes stuff by himself and reports wrong progress to the supervisor.

He sometimes even promises things to be done in next week without having an idea of how much time will it take and without even having a discussion with the implementation team.

I am pretty new to the team and I really don't know how to deal with it. Any suggestions would be helpful.

**Edit: Impact on me -**

As I mentioned, I am pretty new to the team and because I don't understand business property yet, I do understand technical details and a rough idea of how much time it will take which users can't understand. On the other hand, I am also in the team and I will develop the corresponding requirement afterwards.

As of now what I have seen is he tries to impress people and because he is very talkative he doesn't think before speaking.

Comment: Be quiet, get your own work done, and let him hang himself.   He will be found out eventually.

Comment: As long as it doesn't impact you, why is this your problem?

Comment: Is this colleague your team leader or are you somehow expected to deliver what he promises? If not, there is no goal here for you to address.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Your edit just repeats what you already said before. It is not clear why you can't just ignore that colleague and do your own work.

Comment: @MaskedMan: Direct impact is, I have to deliver what he is promising.

Comment: And why is that? What is his role in the team? Why does your boss expect you to deliver what he promises, or rather to put it in another way, why does your boss have him decide what you will deliver?

Comment: @MaskedMan: His role is Developer + Module Lead. There is no direct manager who expects the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58204/discussion-between-masked-man-and-rahul).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to professionally ask someone to give you appropriate and achievable timelines in a project](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/88255/how-to-professionally-ask-someone-to-give-you-appropriate-and-achievable-timelin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably disheartening or annoying, but there's really nothing you can do.  He doesn't work for you, and it's not your job to police after him to make sure he does what he says he's going to do.

It does affect the team, but it's not YOUR team to try and defend against outside criticism.  If your manager is paying attention, the behavior of this co-worker is already a known issue.  Unless the behavior stops you from meeting your **personal** deadlines, you need to *allow* it to continue to cause the least amount of stress for yourself.  At the end of the day, go home and forget about it.

Comment: The old saying "enough rope to hang himself" comes to mind here. +1 for the points about it not being the OP's team. not my monkey, not my circus is another adage that wills work.